# showing json data with angularjs

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

Hi I'm showing some sample data which I get from server using angularjs.

Here I've called **GetNames()** function in `ng-init`. **Is it ok to call that function in ng-init**. Because I need to show data when page loads.

Here is my code.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personController"  >

    <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('personController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.GetNames = function () {
      var httpResponse = $http({
            method: 'POST',
           async: true,
           cache: false,
            url: "http://localhost:55513/Home/GetNames",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
      httpResponse.success(function (data) {
            $scope.names = data;       
       } ); 
    };
    $scope.GetNames();
});
</script>
```

And it works for me.

And also if I use jquery/Ajax for fetching data, even I get the response with data. That data is not loading in the screen. (If I do a postback with a button it loads)
What is the reason for this..

here is my GetNames() function with the jquery/Ajax code..

```
$scope.GetNames = function () {

         $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")",

                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    $scope.names = response;

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: There are `$http` service for http requests, BTW. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using a jquery ajax to update the scope variable, which does not trigger the digest cycle which is responsible to update the UI.

The correct solution to this problem is to use $http service for ajax requests...

Another solution (If you want to know how to make the jquery ajax work) is to use [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

```
success: function (response) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.names = response;
    });
}
```

- [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

Comment: thanks it works. How about the first question I've asked about the place calling GetNames() function since I have to load data when page loading?

Comment: @tarzanbappa since you have a controller why don't you just call `GetNames` after `$scope.GetNames=function(){}` so there won't be any need to have `ng-init`

Comment: @tarzanbappa can you share the complete controller code

Comment: @tarzanbappa but where is the `GetNames` defined... is it in a different controlelr

Comment: Sry for that.Now you can see the complete controller. Previously I called GetNames() instead of $scope.GetNames(). Now its working. 
could you plz check whether are there any improvements  needed?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax is out of capability of angular, you need to wrap like below, it will tell the `$scope.user` is going to update and update the view also

```
 success: function (response) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.user = data;
    });
 },
```

Angular ajax comes with the digest cycle triggering mechanism. then it will automatically change the view also, but jquery is not capable of it.